# Import and read data form EXCEL file on web

Tags: javascript, html, json, excel

Can I import an excel file from computer and read the data I assign in input?

For example, I have 3 input area, 1 for import file excel, 2 remains for assign the start and end data cell I want to assign (A1 - A10). Then create a table showing all data cell I have assigned on my website.

I have read some materials on google, but I get a little bit confusing and not clear about that.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the simplest and tiniest way of reading an *.xslx file in a browser then this library might do **xlsx.core**:

```js
   function handleFile(e) {
     //Get the files from Upload control
        var files = e.target.files;
        var i, f;
     //Loop through files
        for (i = 0, f = files[i]; i != files.length; ++i) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            var name = f.name;
            reader.onload = function (e) {
                var data = e.target.result;

                var result;
                var workbook = XLSX.read(data, { type: 'binary' });
                
                var sheet_name_list = workbook.SheetNames;
                sheet_name_list.forEach(function (y) { /* iterate through sheets */
                    //Convert the cell value to Json
                    var roa = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(workbook.Sheets[y]);
                    if (roa.length > 0) {
                        result = roa;
                    }
                });
               //Get the result
                console.log(result);
            };
            reader.readAsArrayBuffer(f);
        }
    }

  //Change event to dropdownlist
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#files').change(handleFile);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xlsx/0.7.7/xlsx.core.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" id="files" name="files"/>
```